# Objective function of multi-task learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multitask-learning

I have two tasks in hand to train using multi-task learning.

Task 1 - sequence classification task (x1,x2,...,xn -> Y)
Task 2 - sequence to sequence prediction (X1,x2,....,xn -> y1,y2,...,ym)

Two tasks are non-identical, as one is classification and other is sequence prediction (sequence to sequence learning). The loss functions for both tasks are different. Task1 uses cross-entropy loss function, whereas Task2 uses mean-squared-error loss function. I am confused how to define a common loss function (objective function)?

Comment: One common solution is to optimize a weighted sum of the objective functions for each task

Comment: @ArtemMavrin that means first we have to optimize both the losses individually, then optimize both the losses? what would be its equation?

Comment: If your original losses are $L_1,\ldots,L_T$, where $T$ is the number of tasks, then the new loss would be $w_1 L_1 + \cdots + w_T L_T$, where $w_1,\ldots,w_T$ assign weights to each task to emphasize some tasks more heavily than others. You would optimize this weighted sum instead of the individual losses

Comment: I am new machine learning practitioner, so question might be very basic. we need to optimize the weights using SGD, like we optimize the parameters in underlying layers?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. The weights $w_1,\ldots,w_T$ are *hyperparameters*; they are chosen and fixed before training the model. For simplicity, you can start by setting $w_t = 1$ for all tasks $t$, so that you optimize $L_1+\cdots+L_T$. Then when you want to start trading off the performance on one task with the performance on another, you can start tuning the $w_t$'s however you want

Comment: I mean how to optimize these weights? what is the criteria to assign weights to each task. e,g if I have two tasks, then what weights should be given to each task. what is meant by optimizing the weighted sum? second, is this logical to sum cross-entropy and mse error as our joint loss?